# How can I create an About page similar to that of SkyDrive (or any of the other standard applications)?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

When you launch the standard [SkyDrive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneDrive) [Metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) application in Windows 8/8.1 and then go to the Settings charm, and then tap the About link, the charms bar transforms into an About page/panel on the right.

How can I do the same for my application? (I don't even know what it is called.)

Comment: I don't think this is too broad. I didn't know it was called a Flyout, so the answers helped me a lot, and they also helped at least one other person. There is only one possible answer here --- about pages in Windows metro apps all use Flyout. If you have any more guidance on how to reword my question, please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That thing is called Flyout. If you are developing for Windows 8 then I would recommend to go for [Callisto toolkit](http://callistotoolkit.com) it has flyout control.

If you don't want to go with 3rd party SDK. You can also make it your own. Checkout MSDN sample [CharmFlyout - C# XAML Custom Control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CharmFlyout-A-Metro-Flyout-25fe53b6)

If you are developing for Windows 8.1 then 8.1 API has [`SettingsFlyout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout.aspx) control.

[App settings sample - MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-settings-sample-1f762f49)

[Quickstart: Add app settings (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872190.aspx)